# Merge is not defined ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to merge my state with some data I have in another module, but the console logs "merge is not defined" it is similar with mergeDeep. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: results in "cannot read property merge of undefined"

Comment: because set returns a new map. state.set(updatedState) does nothing. you should do state = state.set(updatedState)

Comment: still the same error

Comment: and also there is one more wrong usage. If "state" is a map, then you can not get "data" key as state.data, you should say "state.get("data")".

Comment: after your first comment, I changed merge to : `state.data.merge(action.payload.meetingNote)`

Comment: no. it should be state.get("data").merge(action.payload.meetingNote) and you need to read the documentation

Comment: Still get the same error. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: one last thing could be, if there is no data in state and you try to use merge, you should check it in order to prevent a merge op before creating a data or you hack it as state.get("data", fromJS({})).merge(....)

Comment: okay, I´ll try, thanks a lot, erdysson :) You´re a great guy!